# Css file not loading on Python Anywhere

Tags: python, css, django, pythonanywhere

I have recently begun making a Django project on [PythonAnyhwere.](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)

I have followed the entire tutorial provided by Django for including static files on the project. I have observed the programs work fine on [a site with http](http://iparvez.pythonanywhere.com/blog/home/), but does not work on [a site with https](https://iparvez.pythonanywhere.com/blog/home/).

What could be the reasons and how can I overcome this problem?

Edit : The site is working now, apparently, but I would still like an explanation as to why it WAS working differently, if anyone can provide.
[image: Site on Https]
[image: Site on http]

Comment: The url of your https link is incorrect. https://iparvez.pythonanyhwere.com/blog/home/ you have spelled where as hwere. I tried this https://iparvez.pythonanywhere.com/blog/home/ and it worked well for me

Comment: @ShreyasPrakash Oh yes, it's working now apparently, but I still do not know why this error happened in the first place. I'll edit the question accorfingly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to load your CSS files (or totally static files), you need to follow the steps below:

1- inside settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

2-collect static files using bash console

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

3-you need to enter the Static files directory inside the web tab

check the image below

[static files python anywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrAD3.jpg)

4- reload your web app